# rootBundle.loadString does not read the whole text in file

Tags: flutter, assets, readfile

I have a file named **A#** in the assets folder.

When i read its content with **rootBundle.loadString** not all the data is read.

This is the files content

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
> invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
> Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
> invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
> Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2.

This is the output with print
[image]

Why is part off the text missing?

This is the code that i used

```
final stringA = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/holidays/A#");
print(stringA);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i used **debugPrint** instead of **print** all the text was shown.

There was no problem with **rootBundle.loadString**, but the print command has its limit.